# How to make default writing font bigger in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, font

My current default font in writing emails is Helvetica 12pt. I see it as a very small, and I would like to increase it to 14pt. But right now I have to do it every time I write an email, and I often forget it. I would really like to make Helvetica 14pt as my default writing font. And to clarify, I want it to be changed both for me, and for the recipients of my emails, unlike [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24058/composing-messages-in-apple-mail-displaying-text-on-screen-in-larger-size-witho) (seemingly outdated) question.

There are font settings, but they seem to affect only viewing email, as I want to change the opposite matter, writing emails.

Answer (score 0):

The settings that you specify in Apple Mail's Preferences will apply both to reading (otherwise unformatted) messages, i.e. the display of text-only messages on your machine, and the format of messages that you compose and send out to others.

You'll need to keep two things in mind:

- You need to send your messages as "rich text" or "formatted" mail, otherwise you send out only unformatted text. The corresponding setting is in the Preferences dialogue, unter the "Composing" tab select "Message format: Rich Text".
- It is generally a bad idea to send out formatted mail, although it is more or less the standard nowadays. You don't know about the settings your recipients use, and what looks like a reasonable font size to you may look very different to them.

Comment: In my experience, Mail does not actually send rich text (e.g. html), despite that setting, unless you set the font for each outgoing individually in the New Message pane.  To check this on your own machine, go to the Sent folder and do View > Message > Raw Source on an outgoing and see whether there are html codes for the font name and size or not.  Outlook is an alternative which does send rich text on the basis of default settings.